# Ubuntu Bionic Beaver freezes randomly

Tags: freeze

a few days ago I upgraded my machine (Lenovo ThinkPad T510) from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu Bionic Beaver, and since then my machine freezes somehow randomly when I use LibreOffice or when I look at pictures using Image Viewer. I would like to point out that these aren't big files or pictures, it freezes with pictures less than 1MB. When it freezes, I can move the mouse, but nothing else, and sometimes I can reboot using REISUB but sometimes not even that. I already performed a memtest86+ and it passed 1 full test with no errors found. Other than that, I don't know what else to do to file a bug for this. How are you supposed to file this type of bugs (random freezes) in Ubuntu? I'd like to point out that I never had these freezes in Ubuntu 16.04 using this same machine. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Update #1**: I tried executing "tail -n 99 /var/log/Xorg*.log" (with and without sudo), and I get this: "tail: cannot open '/var/log/Xorg*.log' for reading: No such file or directory". Do I need to enable something to get these logs?

**Update #2:** NOTE:Update removed as I've reached the max amount of characters for the Body of the question.

**Update #3:** @heynnema here's the result of the commands you suggested:

`free -h` :

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.6G        2.2G        123M        205M        5.3G        4.9G
Swap:          979M         64M        915M
```

`sysctl vm.swappiness` :

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

`grep -i swap /etc/fstab` :

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

**Update #4:** @Raffa, here are the results:

`lspci | grep ' VGA '`

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [NVS 3100M] (rev a2)`

`sudo lshw -C display`

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GT218M [NVS 3100M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:cc000000-ccffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:ce000000-cfffffff ioport:2000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

`apt policy xserver-xorg-input-*`

```
xserver-xorg-input-all:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1
  Version table:
     1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:7.7+19ubuntu7 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.9.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
  Candidate: 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.28.1-1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
xserver-xorg-input-joystick-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.6.3-1build1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1:1.6.3-1build1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-dev-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     0.28.1-1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-joystick-dev-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-elographics:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.4.1-1build6
  Version table:
     1:1.4.1-1build6 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dev-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-aiptek:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.4.1-2build1
  Version table:
     1:1.4.1-2build1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: 1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
  Candidate: 1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1.9.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-multitouch:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0~rc3-1
  Version table:
     1.0~rc3-1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-void:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.4.1-1build3
  Version table:
     1:1.4.1-1build3 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-kbd:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.9.0-1
  Version table:
     1:1.9.0-1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.10.6-1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1:2.10.6-1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evtouch:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: 1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3
  Candidate: 1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3
  Version table:
 *** 1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
xserver-xorg-input-libinput:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.27.1-1
  Version table:
     0.27.1-1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.27.1-1
  Version table:
     0.27.1-1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-wacom:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-void-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-mtrack:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3.1-1build2
  Version table:
     0.3.1-1build2 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
xserver-xorg-input-joystick:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.6.3-1build1
  Version table:
     1:1.6.3-1build1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-joystick-dev-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.6.3-1build1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1:1.6.3-1build1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-xwiimote:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.5-1build3
  Version table:
     0.5-1build3 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dev-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.10.6-1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1:2.10.6-1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-joystick-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-dev-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-mtrack-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1.9.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.9.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-mutouch:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.3.0-1build9
  Version table:
     1:1.3.0-1build9 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.10.6-1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1:2.10.6-1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-mouse:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.9.2-1
  Version table:
     1:1.9.2-1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-joystick-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.6.3-1build1
  Version table:
     1:1.6.3-1build1 500
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
```

**Update #5:** @Raffa, I executed the commands you suggested in order to install xserver-xorg-input-all, and rebooted the machine, after which I tested using Image Viewer and LibreOffice Calc, and it froze again, so I rebooted using REISUB. At this point I started to see high CPU usage, but RAM usage remained under 2.5G. First it was slow to transition from pic to pic in Image Viewer, then it froze for about 4 minutes, after that I kept looking at pictures, one video and open a spreadsheet in LibreOffice Calc, it was then when it completely froze. I waited 15 min. approx, and that's when I decided to REISUB.

**Update #6:** @Raffa, I installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput as suggested, and repeated the test as in Update #5, with same results: the system keeps freezing, high CPU usage, RAM memory remained around 1.7G, and swap memory 0G. I did REISUB to reboot.

**Update #7:** @Raffa, I'm using a laptop, so the only things connected are the mouse (USB) and the power cord. I rebooted without the mouse, and tested as in Update #5 and #6, with same results, it keeps frezzing, although this time I didn't notice high CPU usage. Here's the output for `tail -n 400 /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "status installed"` :

```
2020-04-03 19:03:39 status installed libcilkrts5:amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-03 19:03:39 status installed libubsan0:amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-03 19:03:39 status installed libtsan0:amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-03 19:03:39 status installed linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.15.0-91.92
2020-04-03 19:03:39 status installed liblsan0:amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-03 19:03:39 status installed libmpx2:amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-03 19:03:39 status installed dpkg-dev:all 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3
2020-04-03 19:03:40 status installed libfakeroot:amd64 1.22-2ubuntu1
2020-04-03 19:03:40 status installed libalgorithm-diff-perl:all 1.19.03-1
2020-04-03 19:03:40 status installed libc-dev-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-03 19:03:40 status installed manpages-dev:all 4.15-1
2020-04-03 19:03:40 status installed libc6-dev:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-03 19:03:40 status installed libitm1:amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-03 19:03:40 status installed fakeroot:amd64 1.22-2ubuntu1
2020-04-03 19:03:40 status installed libgcc-7-dev:amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-03 19:03:40 status installed libstdc++-7-dev:amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-03 19:03:40 status installed libalgorithm-merge-perl:all 0.08-3
2020-04-03 19:03:40 status installed libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl:amd64 0.04-5
2020-04-03 19:03:40 status installed gcc-7:amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-03 19:03:40 status installed g++-7:amd64 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-03 19:03:40 status installed gcc:amd64 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3
2020-04-03 19:03:41 status installed g++:amd64 4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3
2020-04-03 19:03:41 status installed build-essential:amd64 12.4ubuntu1
2020-04-03 19:03:55 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-04-03 19:03:56 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-03 19:29:23 status installed libpugixml1v5:amd64 1.8.1-7
2020-04-03 19:29:23 status installed libwxbase3.0-0v5:amd64 3.0.4+dfsg-3
2020-04-03 19:29:23 status installed filezilla-common:all 3.28.0-1
2020-04-03 19:29:23 status installed libfilezilla0:amd64 0.11.0-1
2020-04-03 19:29:23 status installed libwxgtk3.0-0v5:amd64 3.0.4+dfsg-3
2020-04-03 19:29:23 status installed filezilla:amd64 3.28.0-1
2020-04-03 19:29:23 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2
2020-04-03 19:29:24 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-03 19:29:26 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-04-03 19:29:26 status installed gnome-menus:amd64 3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1
2020-04-03 19:29:26 status installed hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.17-2
2020-04-03 19:29:26 status installed mime-support:all 3.60ubuntu1
2020-04-04 09:13:03 status installed libgd3:amd64 2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4
2020-04-04 09:13:03 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-04 13:29:59 status installed ubuntu-desktop:amd64 1.417.4
2020-04-04 13:30:00 status installed xorg:amd64 1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1
2020-04-04 13:30:00 status installed xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04:amd64 1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3
2020-04-04 13:30:00 status installed xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04:amd64 1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3
2020-04-04 13:30:01 status installed xserver-xorg-input-all:amd64 1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1
2020-04-04 14:33:29 status installed xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04:amd64 1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3
2020-04-04 14:33:29 status installed xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04:amd64 1:13.3.0-2build1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:29 status installed xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04:amd64 19.0.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:29 status installed xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04:amd64 1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:30 status installed xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04:amd64 1:2.4.0-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:30 status installed xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04:amd64 1:19.0.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:30 status installed xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04:amd64 1:19.0.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:30 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:30 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:30 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:30 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:30 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:30 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:30 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:30 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:30 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:30 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:30 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:31 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:31 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:31 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:31 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:31 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:31 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:31 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:31 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:31 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:31 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:32 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:32 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:32 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:32 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:32 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:32 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:32 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:32 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:32 status installed xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:1.20.5+git20191008-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:33 status installed xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04:amd64 1:0.5.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:33 status installed xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04:amd64 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1ubuntu1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:34 status installed xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04:amd64 1:1.0.16-1~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:34 status installed xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04:amd64 0.1.5-2build2~18.04.1
2020-04-04 14:33:34 status installed xserver-common:all 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4
2020-04-04 14:33:34 status installed xserver-xorg-core:amd64 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4
2020-04-04 14:33:34 status installed xserver-xorg-input-libinput:amd64 0.27.1-1
2020-04-04 14:33:37 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-04-04 14:33:37 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
```

**Update #8:** @Raffa, I did the `sudo apt purge nvidia-*` and the `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` , and so far I haven't experienced any freeze. I repeated the previous test, and more, and it's been working fine. I'll post again if there's any other issue. Thanks a lot for your patience, and advice.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu community. I'm using 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) from past 1 and half year. I had never faced this issue until from last month, even I've started facing this issue. I'm in the middle of debugging the issue using the logs at /var/log/syslog. You also try to find the issue.
One more good news is, this month at 23rd, Ubuntu 20.04 is getting released. Hence until then try to manage or upgrade to 19.10 since you have recently upgraded to Bionic. Let's hope 20.04 will come with fix for major issues like this.

Comment: Does this earlier reply help? https://askubuntu.com/a/1090140/307670

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of ``tail -n 99 /var/log/Xorg*.log

Comment: Hi Raffa, I've editted my question with your suggestion.

Comment: `tail -n 99 /var/log/Xorg*.log ` try now. Sorry typo. :)

Comment: I tried that command, I get the same "No such file or directory" result  :(

Comment: Please do `ls /var/log/X*` and see how many `Xorg` log files are there. The output will be something like `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and maybe `/var/log/Xorg.1.log` and more. do `cat` or tail -n 99 on all of them and add the output.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: To locate the Xorg log file, please run `sudo updatedb` then run `locate "*Xorg*.log"` then run `tail -n 99 ` on the result.

Comment: It looks Xorg related. Please add the output of `lspci | grep ' VGA '` and `sudo lshw -C display` and `apt policy xserver-xorg-input-*`

Comment: `xserver-xorg-input-all` is not installed where it should be. Please install it by running `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all` and then reboot and report back.

Comment: `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` is also not installed where it should be. Please Install `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` like so `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput` then reboot and report back

Comment: Please disconnect all USB and external devices ie (headphones, speakers, cameras, additional monitors ....) and change your keyboard and mouse if you have extra ones or connect them to different USB ports if you don't. Then reboot your computer and see how it goes. Also add the output of `tail -n 400 /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "status installed"` to inspect the lately updated and installed packages.

Comment: Lets rule out video driver issues. Please do `sudo apt purge nvidia-*` then `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` then reboot and see if it gets better.

Comment: Hi Raffa, it's been two days and my system hasn't frozen again. One thing I noticed though, is that I can't adjust the brightness of the screen.

Comment: That is a different issue more common to NVIDIA cards ( adjusting brightness ). I suggest you post a new question on that issue so it gets fixed. Good to hear freezing issue has been solved.

Comment: Please also run `sudo lshw -C display` again and add the current output in your new question, it will help.

Comment: Hi @Raffa, I've created a new question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227049/ubuntu-bionic-beaver-unable-to-adjust-screen-brightness) and included the output of the command you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Diagnosis:

- By looking into the `Xorg` logs, there appears some issues ( crashes ) related in particular to `libinput`:

> ```
> (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"   
> (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
> (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall" 
> (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad' 
> (**) TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall" 
> (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint' 
> (**) ThinkPad Extra Buttons: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall" 
> (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ThinkPad Extra Buttons'
> ```

- By looking into the output of `apt policy xserver-xorg-input-*`, it turns out that both `xserver-xorg-input-all` and `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` are not installed where they should be:

> ```
> xserver-xorg-input-all:
>   Installed: (none)
>   Candidate: 1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1
>   Version table:
>      1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1 500
>         500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
>      1:7.7+19ubuntu7 500
>         500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
>
> xserver-xorg-input-libinput:
>   Installed: (none)
>   Candidate: 0.27.1-1
>   Version table:
>      0.27.1-1 500
>         500 http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
> ```

- By looking into the output of `tail -n 400 /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "status installed"`. Some VGA related packages / drivers appear to might have been affected during the last update.
- By looking into the output of `lspci | grep ' VGA '` and `sudo lshw -C display` it shows you have an `NVIDIA Corporation GT218M` graphics card with the `nouveau` driver in use.

---

## Solution:

1. Install `xserver-xorg-input-all` like so:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

2. Install `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` like so:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput
```

3. Purge the NVIDIA video drivers like so:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
```

4. Install the correct video drivers using the `ubuntu-drivers` tool like so:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

5. Reboot your machine and cross your fingers : ).

Best of luck

Comment: Hello Raffa, I don't have any logs starting from Xorg. In my case only Mouse and Keyboard are freezing. OS seems not freezing. I've asked a question with additional details [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224373/ubuntu-18-04-freezing-frequently-from-past-one-month). Can you take a look?