# Ubuntu 18.04 freezing frequently from past one month

Tags: 18.04, usb, keyboard, mouse, freeze

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 for a long time and I never had issues of freezing until recently from past month I'm facing this issue. But before pointing finger at Ubuntu, I want to make sure which is the actual problem.

These are the things I have tried so far.
1. I saw in a post that, the reason for mouse and/or keyboard getting froze could be lot of dust in the USB ports. So I have cleaned my CPU for 2 times. 1st time I really had dust particles which could create a thick web roll kind of thing. Second time I used vacuum cleaner exhaust to throw away all the dust particles in any corner of SMPS and Proccessor. I also cleaned USB ports with high pressure air.

2. I removed mouse and keyboard and tried reconnecting, still it's not getting detected.

While observing I found out that, I clicked on a link of stack overflow, while my mouse and keyboard froze, the website still loaded without freezing after about 5 seconds. So this concluded that it's not whole OS only USB devices.

I still think this could be the fault of Ubuntu because, both mouse and keyboard can't magically get issue at the same time. Both will work well for some time after hard system reset. So I was looking at system logs. Below are the messages, which I don't understand what went wrong.

```
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop kernel: [42747.580618] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:046D:C05A.0009/input/input13
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop kernel: [42747.580916] hid-generic 0003:046D:C05A.0009: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4/input0
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4"
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 10 was not an MTP device
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event4)
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech USB Optical Mouse'
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 69 paused 0
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: always reports core events
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (II) event4  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (II) event4  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: device set to 1000 DPI
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (II) event4  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: device is a pointer
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (II) event4  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: device removed
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:046D:C05A.0009/input/input13/event4"
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop upowerd[1354]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:046D:C05A.0009
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (II) event4  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (II) event4  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: device set to 1000 DPI
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1809]: (II) event4  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: device is a pointer
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop upowerd[1354]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0
Apr  5 21:48:46 padmahasa-desktop upowerd[1354]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4
Apr  5 21:48:51 padmahasa-desktop colord-sane: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Apr  5 21:49:20 padmahasa-desktop dbus-daemon[1817]: [session uid=1000 pid=1817] Activating service name='org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=1944 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Apr  5 21:49:20 padmahasa-desktop dbus-daemon[1817]: [session uid=1000 pid=1817] Activating service name='org.gnome.Calendar' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=1944 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Apr  5 21:49:20 padmahasa-desktop dbus-daemon[1817]: [session uid=1000 pid=1817] Activating service name='org.gnome.seahorse.Application' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=1944 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Apr  5 21:49:20 padmahasa-desktop dbus-daemon[1817]: [session uid=1000 pid=1817] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider'
Apr  5 21:49:20 padmahasa-desktop dbus-daemon[1817]: [session uid=1000 pid=1817] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Calendar'
Apr  5 21:49:21 padmahasa-desktop dbus-daemon[1817]: [session uid=1000 pid=1817] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.seahorse.Application'
Apr  5 21:49:21 padmahasa-desktop nautilus[4828]: g_key_file_load_from_file: assertion 'file != NULL' failed
Apr  5 21:49:21 padmahasa-desktop nautilus[4828]: Could not establish a connection to Tracker: Failed to load SPARQL backend: Key file does not have group “DomainOntology”
Apr  5 21:49:21 padmahasa-desktop nautilus[4828]: g_queue_pop_head: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
Apr  5 21:49:21 padmahasa-desktop nautilus[4828]: g_queue_foreach: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
Apr  5 21:49:21 padmahasa-desktop nautilus[4828]: g_queue_free: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
Apr  5 21:49:21 padmahasa-desktop nautilus[4828]: g_queue_pop_head: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
Apr  5 21:49:23 padmahasa-desktop nautilus[4828]: g_queue_foreach: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
Apr  5 21:49:23 padmahasa-desktop nautilus[4828]: g_queue_free: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
```

Let me know if you need any additional information.

**Update 1:**

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for padmahasa: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:28 memory:fe000000-fe3fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**2. Output of second command:** apt policy xserver-xorg-input-*

$

```
xserver-xorg-input-all:
  Installed: 1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1
  Candidate: 1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:7.7+19ubuntu7.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:7.7+19ubuntu7 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.9.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     0.28.1-1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-joystick-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.6.3-1build1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1:1.6.3-1build1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-dev-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.28.1-1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     0.28.1-1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-joystick-dev-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-elographics:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.4.1-1build6
  Version table:
     1:1.4.1-1build6 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dev-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-aiptek:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.4.1-2build1
  Version table:
     1:1.4.1-2build1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1.9.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-multitouch:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0~rc3-1
  Version table:
     1.0~rc3-1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-void:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.4.1-1build3
  Version table:
     1:1.4.1-1build3 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-kbd:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.9.0-1
  Version table:
     1:1.9.0-1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.10.6-1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1:2.10.6-1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evtouch:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3
  Version table:
     1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-libinput:
  Installed: 0.27.1-1
  Candidate: 0.27.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.27.1-1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.27.1-1
  Version table:
     0.27.1-1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-wacom:
  Installed: 1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:0.36.1-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
xserver-xorg-input-void-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-mtrack:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3.1-1build2
  Version table:
     0.3.1-1build2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
xserver-xorg-input-joystick:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.6.3-1build1
  Version table:
     1:1.6.3-1build1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-joystick-dev-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.6.3-1build1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1:1.6.3-1build1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-xwiimote:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.5-1build3
  Version table:
     0.5-1build3 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dev-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.10.6-1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1:2.10.6-1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-joystick-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-libinput-dev-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:2.10.5-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-mtrack-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1.9.1-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.9.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.9.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-mutouch:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.3.0-1build9
  Version table:
     1:1.3.0-1build9 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3:14.1
  Version table:
     3:14.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-18.04-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:2.10.6-1~18.04.1
  Version table:
     1:2.10.6-1~18.04.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-mouse:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.9.2-1
  Version table:
     1:1.9.2-1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
xserver-xorg-input-joystick-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.6.3-1build1
  Version table:
     1:1.6.3-1build1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
```

**3. Output of 3rd command:** $ tail -n 999 /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "status installed"

```
2020-04-01 06:17:14 status installed bluez:amd64 5.48-0ubuntu3.4
2020-04-01 06:17:14 status installed systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.39
2020-04-01 06:17:16 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-04-01 06:17:16 status installed dbus:amd64 1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1
2020-04-01 06:17:16 status installed ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-21
2020-04-01 06:17:22 status installed bluez-cups:amd64 5.48-0ubuntu3.4
2020-04-01 06:17:27 status installed bluez-obexd:amd64 5.48-0ubuntu3.4
2020-04-01 06:17:32 status installed libbluetooth3:amd64 5.48-0ubuntu3.4
2020-04-01 06:17:33 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-01 06:17:41 status installed libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 2.28.0-0ubuntu0.18.04.3
2020-04-01 06:17:41 status installed libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 2.28.0-0ubuntu0.18.04.3
2020-04-01 06:17:41 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-01 06:17:54 status installed chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 80.0.3987.149-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2020-04-01 06:17:55 status installed chromium-browser:amd64 80.0.3987.149-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2020-04-01 06:17:55 status installed chromium-browser-l10n:all 80.0.3987.149-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2020-04-01 06:17:55 status installed gnome-menus:amd64 3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1
2020-04-01 06:17:55 status installed hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.17-2
2020-04-01 06:17:56 status installed mime-support:all 3.60ubuntu1
2020-04-01 06:17:56 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2
2020-04-01 06:17:57 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-04-01 06:18:03 status installed gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 2.28.0-0ubuntu0.18.04.3
2020-04-01 06:18:03 status installed gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 2.28.0-0ubuntu0.18.04.3
2020-04-01 06:18:13 status installed gcc-8-base:amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:13 status installed gcc-8-base:i386 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:13 status installed libgcc1:amd64 1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:13 status installed libgcc1:i386 1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:21 status installed libquadmath0:amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:21 status installed libgomp1:amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:21 status installed libatomic1:amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:22 status installed libatomic1:i386 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:22 status installed libtsan0:amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:22 status installed liblsan0:amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:22 status installed libmpx2:amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:22 status installed libstdc++6:amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:22 status installed libstdc++6:i386 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:23 status installed libitm1:amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:23 status installed libcc1-0:amd64 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04
2020-04-01 06:18:23 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-01 08:28:56 status installed libuuid1:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6
2020-04-01 08:28:56 status installed libuuid1:i386 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6
2020-04-01 08:28:58 status installed libblkid1:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6
2020-04-01 08:28:58 status installed libblkid1:i386 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6
2020-04-01 08:28:59 status installed libfdisk1:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6
2020-04-01 08:29:01 status installed libsmartcols1:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6
2020-04-01 08:29:03 status installed libmount1:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6
2020-04-01 08:29:03 status installed libmount1:i386 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6
2020-04-01 08:29:03 status installed fdisk:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6
2020-04-01 08:29:07 status installed util-linux:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6
2020-04-01 08:29:30 status installed libasound2-data:all 1.1.3-5ubuntu0.4
2020-04-01 08:29:31 status installed mount:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6
2020-04-01 08:29:31 status installed libasound2:amd64 1.1.3-5ubuntu0.4
2020-04-01 08:29:31 status installed libasound2:i386 1.1.3-5ubuntu0.4
2020-04-01 08:29:32 status installed uuid-runtime:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6
2020-04-01 08:29:32 status installed python3-problem-report:all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.13
2020-04-01 08:29:33 status installed code:amd64 1.43.2-1585036376
2020-04-01 08:29:33 status installed rfkill:amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.6
2020-04-01 08:29:33 status installed obs-studio:amd64 25.0.3-0obsproject0~bionic
2020-04-01 08:29:33 status installed python3-apport:all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.13
2020-04-01 08:29:36 status installed apport:all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.13
2020-04-01 08:29:36 status installed apport-gtk:all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.13
2020-04-01 08:29:36 status installed systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.39
2020-04-01 08:29:39 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-04-01 08:29:39 status installed gnome-menus:amd64 3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1
2020-04-01 08:29:39 status installed hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.17-2
2020-04-01 08:29:39 status installed mime-support:all 3.60ubuntu1
2020-04-01 08:29:39 status installed ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-21
2020-04-01 08:29:39 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2
2020-04-01 08:29:39 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-03 08:33:11 status installed python3-apport:all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.14
2020-04-03 08:33:18 status installed python3-problem-report:all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.14
2020-04-03 08:33:29 status installed apport:all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.14
2020-04-03 08:33:29 status installed hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.17-2
2020-04-03 08:33:29 status installed ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-21
2020-04-03 08:33:29 status installed systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.39
2020-04-03 08:33:31 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-04-03 08:33:36 status installed apport-gtk:all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.14
2020-04-03 08:33:36 status installed mime-support:all 3.60ubuntu1
2020-04-03 08:33:37 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2
2020-04-03 08:33:37 status installed gnome-menus:amd64 3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1
2020-04-05 00:22:56 status installed atom:amd64 1.45.0
2020-04-05 00:22:56 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2
2020-04-05 00:22:57 status installed gnome-menus:amd64 3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1
2020-04-05 00:22:58 status installed mime-support:all 3.60ubuntu1
2020-04-05 08:33:47 status installed libgd3:amd64 2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4
2020-04-05 08:33:47 status installed libgd3:i386 2.2.5-4ubuntu0.4
2020-04-05 08:33:48 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.27-3ubuntu1
2020-04-06 08:12:14 status installed firefox:amd64 74.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2020-04-06 08:12:14 status installed gnome-menus:amd64 3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1
2020-04-06 08:12:15 status installed hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.17-2
2020-04-06 08:12:15 status installed mime-support:all 3.60ubuntu1
2020-04-06 08:12:15 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2
2020-04-06 08:12:17 status installed man-db:amd64 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1
2020-04-06 08:12:22 status installed firefox-locale-en:amd64 74.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
2020-04-07 08:48:33 status installed linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.15.0-96.97
2020-04-07 08:48:56 status installed linux-modules-4.15.0-96-generic:amd64 4.15.0-96.97
2020-04-07 08:48:56 status installed linux-headers-4.15.0-96:all 4.15.0-96.97
2020-04-07 08:48:57 status installed linux-image-4.15.0-96-generic:amd64 4.15.0-96.97
2020-04-07 08:48:58 status installed linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-96-generic:amd64 4.15.0-96.97
2020-04-07 08:49:05 status installed linux-headers-4.15.0-96-generic:amd64 4.15.0-96.97
2020-04-07 08:49:05 status installed linux-image-generic:amd64 4.15.0.96.87
2020-04-07 08:49:05 status installed linux-headers-generic:amd64 4.15.0.96.87
2020-04-07 08:49:05 status installed linux-generic:amd64 4.15.0.96.87
2020-04-07 08:49:28 status installed linux-image-4.15.0-96-generic:amd64 4.15.0-96.97
```

**4. Also I'm getting "Low speed USB device" message.**

$

```
Apr  7 20:01:03 padmahasa-desktop anacron[13027]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Apr  7 20:08:05 padmahasa-desktop kernel: [37450.521244] usb 1-1.4: reset low-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
Apr  7 20:08:07 padmahasa-desktop kernel: [37452.337312] usb 1-1.4: reset low-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
Apr  7 20:08:11 padmahasa-desktop kernel: [37456.478074] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 31
Apr  7 20:08:11 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7635]: (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech USB Optical Mouse
Apr  7 20:08:11 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7635]: (**) Option "fd" "48"
Apr  7 20:08:11 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7635]: (II) event4  - Logitech USB Optical Mouse: device removed
Apr  7 20:08:11 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7635]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Apr  7 20:08:11 padmahasa-desktop /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[7635]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
Apr  7 20:08:11 padmahasa-desktop gnome-shell[7770]: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
Apr  7 20:08:11 padmahasa-desktop upowerd[1488]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:046D:C05A.001B
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo lshw -C display` and `apt policy xserver-xorg-input-*` and `tail -n 999 /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "status installed"`

Comment: @Raffa, I've updated the question with the output of the commands you have provided.

Comment: I see you upgraded to a new kernel today. Is there any improvement with the new kernel? If not, please try booting to an older kernel. One that was installed before this issue happened and see if the issue is present. If present then probably it is a hardware issue either mouse/keyboard, USB port or controller. To narrow this, disconnect USB/HDMI hardware and cables and reconnect them one by one as well as connecting to different ports until you find the faulty one. There is also a chance that video drivers are to blame so please run `sudo lshw -C display` and post the output.

Comment: You ran the command incomplete like so `sudo lshw -C` while it should be `sudo lshw -C display`. As for the message `reset low-speed USB ...`. This means the device gets disconnected ( that's why mouse and keyboard stop working ) for any of the reasons mentioned in my comment above. As for the system itself, it is ok and not freezing as you noted. So in short it is ether new kernel has no good support for mouse/keyboard or it is actually a hardware problem. Waiting for your update.

Comment: @Raffa, There were 2 Kernels, 4.15.0-91 and 4.15.0-96. I selected the old one (91) from Grub menu. Still the problem exists. I've updated the "lshw" output. About diagnosing USB ports, I didn't get whether you are asking me to remove the devices from outside the CPU or you are asking me to diagnose by removing the cables attached to Mother board. But one other observation I already have done is, when the mouse completely freezes, I have tried reconnecting them to other USB ports, but it will not work until next system restart.

Comment: I meant to disconnect the USB/HDMI cables from the ports outside the machine. Limit the connected devices ( speakers, microphone, headphones, monitors, USB drives, mouse/keyboard .... etc ) and preferably try changing mouse and keyboard with different ones if you have spare ones. `low-speed USB device` usually means a mouse or a keyboard and `reset low-speed USB device` means there is faulty electrical signal due to probably faulty USB and sometimes HDMI cable or device.

Comment: Your display card `Intel integrated` rarely has issues with drivers as it has good enough support in Ubuntu and the correct driver `i915` is in use. So I suggest you rule out VGA driver related issues.

Comment: @Raffa, I've not much bothered about drivers until now in Ubuntu. Not having graphic card could be another reason for not exploring much on drivers. "faulty electrical signal", this sounds like the system logs I've seen using "Logs" app -> important -> system -> "usb 2-1-port4: over-current condition". The same shows for rest of the 3 ports. Regarding ruling out VGA driver issues, is there is any command I can start with?

Comment: Actually what I meant by ruling out VGA driver issues is there is no need to worry about it as it seems not to be the cause in your case. So it appears to be either faulty mouse and/or keyboard which is common and it is simply solved by changing them or a faulty USB controller on the motherboard which is not common but requires changing the motherboard.

Comment: Requires changing motherboard? That sounds scary @Raffa. Even it's  tough to get out of home in this pandemic situation. Anyway thank you for helping me out for diagnosing the issue. I'll try to find out whether it's just mouse or the motherboard which have the problem. If you can post this as answer I can accept that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
kernel: [37450.521244] usb 1-1.4: reset low-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
kernel: [37452.337312] usb 1-1.4: reset low-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
kernel: [37456.478074] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 31
```

means that a USB device on port number 4 gets disconnected, that's probably why mouse or keyboard stop working. As for the system itself, it looks OK and not freezing as you noted.

The reason for this is either the new kernel has no good support for mouse/keyboard or it is actually a hardware problem.

Please try booting to an older kernel. One that was installed before this issue happened and see if the issue is present. If present then probably it is a hardware issue either mouse/keyboard, USB port or controller.

To narrow this down, limit the connected USB/HDMI devices ( speakers, microphone, headphones, monitors, USB drives, mouse/keyboard .... etc ) and preferably try changing mouse and keyboard with different ones if you have spare ones. Disconnect USB/HDMI hardware and cables and reconnect them one by one as well as connecting to different ports until you find the faulty one and change it with a new one.

---

**Notice:**

`low-speed USB device` usually means a mouse or a keyboard and `reset low-speed USB device` most likely means there was faulty electrical signal due to probably faulty USB and sometimes HDMI cable or device.

This means it is most likely either faulty mouse and/or keyboard which is common and it is simply solved by changing them or a faulty USB port/controller on the motherboard which is not common but requires changing the motherboard.

Comment: Any thoughts on "Over current condition" found in the logs, "Logs" app -> important -> system -> "usb 2-1-port4: over-current condition"? If I remember correctly, I'm seeing this log from the day 1 of using 18.04 Ubuntu (Probably from past 1 and half years), But I've never faced mouse issue like this.

Comment: @learner As for "Over current condition" I can't suggest anything. The clear signs are the `reset low-speed USB device number 31` and `USB disconnect, device number 31` and they both state that the USB device gets reset and disconnected after a while and no more I can suggest than what is in the answer. Best of luck

Comment: Thank you. I tried using my mouse in my office's laptop, it got frozen there also. I borrowed a mouse from my cousin. As of now, it's working fine. The only suspicion I had was, is it because of "Over current" problem, my mouse was screwed. That's why I pointed that out. Thank you again.