# Ubuntu 20.04 freezing

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, nvidia-geforce, codecs, partial-upgrade

When restart Ubuntu 20.04,it becomes freeze, doesn't work touchpad and keyboard. Nvidia GeForce GTX1650 graphics installed in my machine.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1224086

Answer (score 0):

Try choosing a different kernel from Advanced Options in the GRUB menu.

Comment: It couldn't work.