# Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop Freezing (Mouse moves but unresponsive)

Tags: 18.04, crash, nouveau, systemd-logind

Lately my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop machine has been freezing. I can still move the mouse around, but clicking doesn't do anything, and no keyboard commands are recognized. It will not response to Ctrl-Alt-Backspace, but REISUB will shut it down. I can SSH into the machine as well.

When I look at syslog, here's the crash today:

```
Jan 26 17:49:54 meeks kernel: [53943.653157] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: write fault at 0000244000 engine 00 [GR] client 0f [GPC0/PROP_0] reason 02 [PTE] on channel 13 [007f4e9000 systemd-logind[1746]]
Jan 26 17:49:54 meeks kernel: [53943.653163] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: channel 13: killed
Jan 26 17:49:54 meeks kernel: [53943.653165] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
Jan 26 17:49:54 meeks kernel: [53943.653169] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
Jan 26 17:50:28 meeks kernel: [53977.661464] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: slack[6821]: failed to idle channel 20 [slack[6821]]
Jan 26 17:50:43 meeks kernel: [53992.661575] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: slack[6821]: failed to idle channel 20 [slack[6821]]
Jan 26 17:50:43 meeks kernel: [53992.661685] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: read fault at 0000013000 engine 07 [HOST0] client 07 [HOST_CPU] reason 02 [PTE] on channel 20 [007f1cc000 slack[6821]]
Jan 26 17:50:43 meeks kernel: [53992.661694] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: channel 20: killed
Jan 26 17:50:43 meeks kernel: [53992.661696] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
Jan 26 17:50:43 meeks kernel: [53992.661711] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
```

Here's another example from yesterday:

```
Jan 25 06:23:46 meeks kernel: [14531.638260] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: write fault at 0000240000 engine 00 [GR] client 0f [GPC0/PROP_0] reason 02 [PTE] on channel 13 [007f4e9000 systemd-logind[1702]]
Jan 25 06:23:46 meeks kernel: [14531.638267] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: channel 13: killed
Jan 25 06:23:46 meeks kernel: [14531.638268] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
Jan 25 06:23:46 meeks kernel: [14531.638273] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.901549] CPU5: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 30066)
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.901549] CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 30066)
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.901568] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 124706)
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.901568] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 124706)
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.901569] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 124706)
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.901570] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 124706)
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.901573] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 124706)
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.901574] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 124706)
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.901575] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 124706)
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.901576] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 124706)
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.902621] CPU5: Core temperature/speed normal
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.902621] CPU1: Core temperature/speed normal
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.902623] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.902624] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.902624] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.902625] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.902625] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.902626] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.902648] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
Jan 25 06:23:59 meeks kernel: [14544.902648] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
Jan 25 06:24:29 meeks kernel: [14574.481259] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: slack[11445]: failed to idle channel 18 [slack[11445]]
Jan 25 06:24:44 meeks kernel: [14589.480973] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: slack[11445]: failed to idle channel 18 [slack[11445]]
Jan 25 06:24:44 meeks kernel: [14589.481019] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: read fault at 0000013000 engine 07 [HOST0] client 07 [HOST_CPU] reason 02 [PTE] on channel 18 [007f3e8000 slack[11445]]
Jan 25 06:24:44 meeks kernel: [14589.481026] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: channel 18: killed
Jan 25 06:24:44 meeks kernel: [14589.481028] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
Jan 25 06:24:44 meeks kernel: [14589.481037] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
```

Motherboard: B250M Pro4

Graphics Card: Asus GT 710 (recently installed, freezing definitely happened before installing, though freeze may be happening more since installation?)

Ram: 4x16GB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous (2 are 2667 MHz, 2 are 2133 MHz)

Hard drives:

```
# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            32422652         0  32422652   0% /dev
tmpfs            6489276      2188   6487088   1% /run
/dev/sdc5       19091540  16451780   1646892  91% /
tmpfs           32446360    406376  32039984   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           32446360         0  32446360   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0          2560      2560         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/748
/dev/loop3           384       384         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/570
/dev/loop1          2304      2304         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/145
/dev/loop2        144128    144128         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
/dev/loop6        144128    144128         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/100
/dev/loop7        223232    223232         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
/dev/loop5          1024      1024         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/93
/dev/loop4         66432     66432         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop8        224256    224256         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop9         56832     56832         0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop11       165376    165376         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop13       100352    100352         0 100% /snap/core/10583
/dev/loop10        56704     56704         0 100% /snap/core18/1932
/dev/loop12          384       384         0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/550
/dev/loop14         2304      2304         0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
/dev/loop15         2560      2560         0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/826
/dev/loop16        63616     63616         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop17         1024      1024         0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/100
/dev/loop18       166784    166784         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop19       100224    100224         0 100% /snap/core/10577
/dev/sdb1      960774412 318087732 642686680  34% /data
/dev/sdc6      210475628 120355016  79359348  61% /home
vmpool         696824704 607706496  89118208  88% /vms
tmpfs            6489272        16   6489256   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs            6489272        36   6489236   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs            6489272         0   6489272   0% /run/user/0
```

Happy to pull other information as it would be helpful. Would love to figure out how to troubleshoot this kind of issue.

Comment: If you can still move the mouse around, your Ubuntu system is still functioning (you can likely switch to text terminal to explore issues; eg. Ctrl+Alt+F4).  From your description it sounds like your GUI/desktop has just somewhat frozen, (X is still working as mouse moves) so can you switch to text terminal? login and explore?  Are there any .crash files in /var/crash?  (it's possible there aren't as you're I get a looping and not crash from your description, but I could be wrong).  If you explore what is running? do you get clues?  `top`, `iotop`, etc...  Have you made any recent changes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Bionic Beaver freezes randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224086/ubuntu-bionic-beaver-freezes-randomly)

Comment: @guiverc - there are two files in /var/crash, but the timestamps are diff to the freeze up. I have not been able to get Ctrl-Alt-f4 to work, but I can SSH in from my laptop. I tried checking top from SSH last time. My VMs are at the top, but not more than usually (I typically keep a terminal with `glances` running). The only recent change is the new graphics card, but it was happening before that (though I would say maybe less often?)

@Raffa - Maybe? I've run the commands. The two installs were already there, the purge didn't remove anything, but the autoinstall did something, so we'll see?