# Screen freeze and other issues with HP envy (Ryzen 5 2500U, AMD Vega 8 mobile graphics)

Tags: 20.04, amdgpu, amd-ryzen

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 on my Laptop with Ryzen 5 2500U processor.

1. I am facing frequent screen freeze issue and I have to restart the laptop everytime it happens.
2. Also, touchpad sometimes doesn't work and I have to restart the laptop for the same.

Can anyone please help me to point out what might be the root cause?
I just expect my laptop to work without having any freeze issue and remain stable for days without having to restart.
Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Bionic Beaver freezes randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224086/ubuntu-bionic-beaver-freezes-randomly)

Comment: No. The mentioned link has to do with NVIDIA gpu and drivers. I have a AMD processor with AMD Vega 8 mobile GPU.

Comment: I have the same processor and I feel your pain, it is getting better lately, after 2 years of waiting (it is possible I have a hardware issue, but there seems to be too many betters and worsers for that). I can have a lockup on keyboard but the sound from a video keeps on running, for a while. heres a dump from my travels.... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70377/bug-soft-lockup-cpu-stuck-for-x-seconds ....

Comment: bios select integrated graphics
disable c-states
clocksource=jiffies to kernel

--- cat /var/log/syslog* ---  apart from that wait for updates and AMD-Linux cooperation. risk a firmware update if you must. given that I killed Windows off this machine, I cannot compare, which would be an interesting observation from someone with same CPU.