# Ubuntu constantly freezng

Tags: dual-boot, freeze, ram, swap, drag-and-drop

I use a HP Elitebook 8460p an I dual boot with Windows. Ubuntu constantly goes into Drag and Drop mode and freezes with only the mouse responding.I wan to know if this has to do with hardware or RAM [Image of my RAM and swap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBwH3.png)

Comment: You've provided no specifics are to your Ubuntu product, or release details. Are you asking about Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Desktop? Ubuntu Server? or something else? What release of the product?  Are your file-systems all local? or is network traffic involved in your *drag and drop* .... Being specific with details allow us to respond with fewer guesses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Bionic Beaver freezes randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224086/ubuntu-bionic-beaver-freezes-randomly)