# 22.04: Help diagnosing why my session crashes about every other day; journal logs attached

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 22.10, logs

My session crashes about every other day. The screen goes blank for a few seconds, and then displays the login screen, opening to a new session.

I haven't identified a pattern of things I might be doing, tried to pay attention to that but nothing stands out. I checked the journal logs and think I found the place where the crash occurred, but I don't know what I'm looking at.

Thanks for taking the time.

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04

KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7

KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0

Qt Version: 5.15.3

Kernel Version: 5.15.0-56-generic (64-bit)

Graphics Platform: X11

Processors: 4 × Intel® Xeon® CPU E31225 @ 3.10GHz

Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM

Graphics Processor: NV167

```
12/7/22 10:45 AM    dbus-daemon apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/freedesktop/PowerManagement/Inhibit" interface="org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit" member="Inhibit" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.PowerManagement" pid=332559 label="snap.chromium.chromium" peer_pid=2015 peer_label="unconfined"
12/7/22 10:45 AM    NetworkManager  <warn>  [1670431521.2422] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::ee3d:d890:315a:dc61]: failure 95 (Operation not supported)
12/7/22 10:45 AM    NetworkManager  <warn>  [1670431523.2442] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::c157:76b4:4907:523d]: failure 95 (Operation not supported)
12/7/22 10:45 AM    NetworkManager  <warn>  [1670431525.2467] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::1c56:f033:9cef:d72a]: failure 95 (Operation not supported)
12/7/22 10:45 AM    NetworkManager  <warn>  [1670431527.2481] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::bfa9:876f:860:6c11]: failure 95 (Operation not supported)
12/7/22 10:45 AM    NetworkManager  <warn>  [1670431529.2483] ipv6ll[7d0a936393bda040,ifindex=2]: changed: no IPv6 link local address to retry after Duplicate Address Detection failures (back off)
12/7/22 10:45 AM    kernel  nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: fault 01 [VIRT_WRITE] at 000000000e802000 engine 40 [gr] client 13 [GPC1/PROP_0] reason 00 [PDE] on channel 2 [00ff5ab000 Xorg[1616]]
12/7/22 10:45 AM    kernel  nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: channel 2: killed
12/7/22 10:45 AM    kernel  nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
12/7/22 10:45 AM    kernel  nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
12/7/22 10:45 AM    kernel  nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1616]: channel 2 killed!
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd Started crash report submission.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    whoopsie    [10:45:38] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    NetworkManager  <warn>  [1670431539.2561] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::b121:a159:cbf7:bc91]: failure 95 (Operation not supported)
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd Started crash report submission.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    kscreen_backend_launcher    The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
12/7/22 10:45 AM    baloorunner The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
12/7/22 10:45 AM    pulseaudio  X11 I/O error handler called
12/7/22 10:45 AM    pulseaudio  X11 I/O error exit handler called, preparing to tear down X11 modules
12/7/22 10:45 AM    org.kde.kmtpd5  The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
12/7/22 10:45 AM    kglobalaccel5   The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
12/7/22 10:45 AM    kactivitymanagerd   The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
12/7/22 10:45 AM    xdg-desktop-portal-kde  The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd plasma-kscreen.service: Consumed 5.777s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd plasma-baloorunner.service: Consumed 3.825s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd plasma-kglobalaccel.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd plasma-kglobalaccel.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd plasma-kglobalaccel.service: Consumed 6.856s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service: Consumed 29.631s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    org.kde.kmtpd5  QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal KDEDModule::moduleDeleted(KDEDModule*): Pointers are not supported: KDEDModule*
12/7/22 10:45 AM    org.kde.kmtpd5  Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
12/7/22 10:45 AM    org.kde.kmtpd5  Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
12/7/22 10:45 AM    whoopsie    [10:45:40] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd plasma-kactivitymanagerd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd plasma-kactivitymanagerd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd plasma-kactivitymanagerd.service: Consumed 8.245s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd app-org.kde.kate-5c418354ff724add9c9200fe4c5f61cd.scope: Consumed 1.092s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd app-org.kde.kate-7ba8a92e7a1b4fb9b671dd85b9ca2d07.scope: Consumed 2.115s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd app-org.kde.kate-843912c64bbb4d8f9bd60a03e23a37a2.scope: Consumed 2.263s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd app-org.kde.kate-dddbc442cfcc4b43a3059e822d4ee45f.scope: Consumed 2.020s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd app-org.kde.kate-4ccb5b709a254c8889505c7875c50a01.scope: Consumed 1.188s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd app-org.kde.kate-199b7d4e0c62487fa2349b5698930c29.scope: Consumed 2.101s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd app-org.kde.kate-d5eb742dd0be4b6fba1c87b11440ba89.scope: Consumed 2.131s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd plasma-xdg-desktop-portal-kde.service: Consumed 12.161s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm-helper [PAM] Closing session
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm-helper pam_unix(sddm:session): session closed for user william
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm-helper pam_kwallet5(sddm:session): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_close_session
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm-helper pam_kwallet5(sddm:setcred): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_setcred
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm-helper [PAM] Ended.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Auth: sddm-helper exited successfully
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Socket server stopping...
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Socket server stopped.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Display server stopping...
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd-logind  Session 3 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd app-autokey\x2dqt-143d7cabd7304668809d65a3de58e9d6.scope: Consumed 5min 46.116s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd app-org.kde.kate-f5f2b717484c4edaacceac4ecdfeba42.scope: Consumed 2min 53.082s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    polkitd(authority=local)    Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:3 (system bus name :1.68, object path /org/kde/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd app-org.kde.dolphin-d85be9386f2941a6aec46b367e26292b.scope: Consumed 2min 27.315s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Display server stopped.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Running display stop script  "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xstop"
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Removing display ":0" ...
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Adding new display on vt 1 ...
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Loading theme configuration from ""
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Display server starting...
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Adding cookie to "/var/run/sddm/{91c93765-8d8b-4d86-a8ff-ca7ac82b0e53}"
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Running: /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{91c93765-8d8b-4d86-a8ff-ca7ac82b0e53} -background none -noreset -displayfd 18 -seat seat0 vt1
12/7/22 10:45 AM    NetworkManager  <warn>  [1670431541.2601] platform-linux: do-add-ip6-address[2: fe80::fb52:5bf8:6393:8a1b]: failure 95 (Operation not supported)
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd snap.chromium.chromium.9b88d30d-7f25-4841-80b7-38091cebb3ca.scope: Consumed 2h 15min 7.496s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd pulseaudio.service: Consumed 10min 13.534s CPU time.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Setting default cursor
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Running display setup script  "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup"
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Display server started.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Socket server starting...
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Socket server started.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Loading theme configuration from "/usr/share/sddm/themes/ubuntu-theme/theme.conf"
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm    Greeter starting...
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm-helper [PAM] Starting...
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm-helper [PAM] Authenticating...
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm-helper [PAM] returning.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    sddm-helper pam_unix(sddm-greeter:session): session opened for user sddm(uid=119) by (uid=0)
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd Created slice User Slice of UID 119.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/119...
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd-logind  New session 181 of user sddm.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd Finished User Runtime Directory /run/user/119.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd Starting User Manager for UID 119...
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user sddm(uid=119) by (uid=0)
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd Queued start job for default target Main User Target.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd Created slice User Application Slice.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd Created slice User Core Session Slice.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd Reached target Paths.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd Reached target Timers.
12/7/22 10:45 AM    systemd Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket...
```

Comment: That suggests probable video driver/card issues ... Does the crash happen mostly under heavy video processing e.g. when playing videos?

Comment: Oddly, no. Not during rendering in KDEnlive or watching YouTube of VLC. I did have several tabs open in Chromium - six or seven is usual, but it can go to a couple dozen when I'm working.

Comment: I would look into `/var/log/Xorg*` logs.

Comment: Fatal server error:
[349085.335] (EE) Caught signal 6 (Aborted). Server aborting

Google isn't much help, there.

Comment: Things to consider 1)Read this similar post for diagnosis procedure https://askubuntu.com/q/1224086 2)Update your machine’s BIOS if there is an update from motherboard vendor 3)Consider installing the recommended nVidia proprietary driver listed in system update app under device drivers … In that order and stop if your issue is resolved by the first or the second recommendation

Comment: Will do, and comment for future readers.