# who exactly responds to a command entered in a alt-F2 window?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, xorg, gnome-shell

I am trying to determine who is responsible for the frequent screen freezes that I am having after the screen has been "blanked" by the 15-min power timeout.

When the screen freezes, the mouse can be moved around, but cannot select anything.

The keyword is "dead" except for "alt-F2". (TAB and windows keys do not function. Ctl-ALT-T will sometimes respond with a terminal window.)

If, however, I press alt-F2 and enter "restart" in the window, the system will sometimes recover. If it does not. then I have to resort to a power-off reboot to recover the system.

So, my quesion is: "Who is responding to the "restart" command?" and "What is it really doing?"

```
  Time/Date Stamp:  Thursday 8 Dec 2022 02:55:06
         Hostname:  wb4alm-07
 Operating System:  GNU/Linux
      Kernel Name:  Linux
   Kernel Release:  5.15.0-53-generic
   Kernel Version:  #59-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 17 18:53:30 UTC 2022
                     
        Processor:  Vendor ID:      AuthenticAMD
        Processor:  Model name:     AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor,  1.4 - 4.0 GHz
        Processor:  CPU(s):         8
        Processor:  Architecture:   x86_64
        Processor:  Byte Order:     Little Endian
                     
    Gnome Version:  GNOME Shell 42.5
 Windowing System:  x11
                     
    Graphics Card:  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)
 Nvidia CLI Query:  nvidia-settings:  version 510.47.03
    Nvidia Driver:    Attribute 'NvidiaDriverVersion' (wb4alm-07:1.0): 470.141.10
  Screen Position:    Attribute 'ScreenPosition' (wb4alm-07:1.0): x=0, y=0, width=2560, height=1440

''''
```

Comment: That is gnome-shell … responding and restarting … restart is an internal gnome-shell command that reloads your gnome session.

Comment: @raffa  Interesting, so Gnome is running "okay". Does that imply that my hang is X11, or maybe the screen driver or one of the many "routines" between them?

Comment: Please see this similar post for further diagnosis *please read the comments on that post* https://askubuntu.com/q/1444471/968501

Comment: @Raffa  thank you for the assistance, but due to the fact that grqphic problems have reoccured everytime UBUNTU 22.04.1 does a software update, I have decided to abandon UBUNTU after 16 years of use. This is even after multiple times (4+) of doing a fresh install of UBUNTU 22.04.1. Surprisingly enough, Mint 21 runs on the exact same hardware with no dificulties or faults.